# expected ')' error in a c++ code

Tags: c++, bgi

This is a Bresenham algorithm for a line in the first positive octant. The code is almost from the http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/goa/mallinnus/lines/bresenh.html. but it doesnt work and the turbo c++ says there is an error in the line 4, ") EXPECTED". I really don't know how to solve it. I would be happy if there is any help.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>
void LINE(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int dy = y2 - y1;
    int y = y1;
    int e = 0;
    for (int x = x1; x <= x2; x++)
    {

        putpixel(x, y, color);
        e += dy;
    }
}
 int main()
{
    int x1, x2, y1, y2, color, gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "..\\bgi");
    cout << "\n Enter Start Point:";
    cin >> x1 >> y1;
    cout << "Enter End Point:";
    cin >> x2 >> y2;
    cout << "Enter your Favorite Color:";
    cin >> color;
    line(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: clearly it's spelled "color"

Comment: @ArunA.S I wouldn't think so upon seeing the dreaded `<grahpics.h>`.  It's amazing how many people are still told to use turbo C++.

Comment: The issue is caused by `void main`.  The `main` function returns an `int` to the operating system.  Always.

Comment: @ArunA.S this is not my fault...this is because of the university.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void Bresenham(int x1,int y1, int x2, int y2, colour)
                                              ^ you forgot the type here
```

It should be

```
void Bresenham(int x1,int y1, int x2, int y2, int colour)
```

( But you are not even using this function in your code )

You should also use `int main()` over `void main()`

```
int main()
  {
     // your code
    return 0;
  }
```

You also have an error here

```
cout>>"Enter your Favorite Colour:";
     ^
     here
```

it should be

```
cout << "Enter your Favorite Colour:";
```

and

```
cin<<colour;
```

should be

```
cin >> colour;
```

You also have an extra parameter in your call yo `line()`. Remove that `colour` from there . It should be

```
line( x1 , y1 , x2 , y2 );
```

If you want to set the color, use

```
setcolor( /* color code */ );
```

These are the color codes

```
 0   BLACK
 1   BLUE
 2   GREEN
 3   CYAN
 4   RED
 5   MAGENTA
 6   BROWN
 7   LIGHTGRAY
 8   DARKGRAY
 9   LIGHTBLUE
 10  LIGHTGREEN
 11  LIGHTCYAN
 12  LIGHTRED
 13  LIGHTMAGENTA
 14  YELLOW
 15  WHITE
```

Example, to get RED, you use

```
setcolor( 4 );
```

Comment: i made the corrections but it didnt worked.

Comment: @navid94 You need to be a little more descriptive than "it didnt work"

Comment: it gives an error in the line 30: Extra parameter in call to line(int, int, int, int) and line 33: Function should return a value

Comment: @navid94  Read the end of my answer.

Comment: @ArunA.S  now it just gives an error in line 33: Function should return a value

Comment: put a `return 0;` at the end of `main()` function.

Comment: @ArunA.S would you by any chance know that how can i let the user to decide to chose the color?

Comment: @navid94 , Updated. But you will have to check which color the user chose and call the `setcolor()` based on that ( you'll need to hard code that ) .